# How to make wordpress navigation menu to be localize

Tags: wordpress

I want to make my wordpress menus to be localize but im stuck on to how can i make it. I tried the wp_nav_menu() parameters 'link_before' and 'link_after' and insert  but cannot make it done. Please shed some light. thanks

```
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <?php

        $args = array(
          'menu'        => 'header-menu',
          'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
          'container'   => 'false',
          'link_before' => '<?php _e(\'', 
          'link_after'  => ' \', \'text_domain\'); ?>'
        );

        wp_nav_menu( $args );

      ?>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Its encouraged to share your code so that people can see what you are trying to do

Comment: just added. thanks